# pdo dbf files and queries

Tags: php, odbc, oledb

Good day everyone, i have an application that uses .dbf files to store data and i would like to run some queries on those files. the problem is that i don't know how .. i've spoken with the people from support about it and they told me that i can an ODBC driver or the dedicated one for visual foxpro Ole DB. I found something called dabse in php manual yet on php 5.3 it doesn't support it or i didn't install it right because it didn't work, from what i've read on google seems that it supports until php 5.2 or something like that. 
Can you help me figure it how to do it ? i've googled around but couldn't find anything that might help me out.

Edit

```
$excelFile = realpath('C:\\db\\article.dbf');
$excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
$dsn = "DRIVER={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=C:\\db\\article.dbf;DefaultDir=$excelDir;Exclusive=NO;collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";
$conn=odbc_connect($dsn,"","");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articole.dbf";
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
```

The Error:

```
Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] External table is not in the expected format., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in E:\public_html\odbc\index.php on line 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have SQL Server? You could create a linked server to the DBF files. Check out this link:

[Linked Server](http://blog.dbase.integralwebsolutions.co.za/2008/10/accessing-your-dbf-tables-via-linked.html)

See also these links for querying DBase or Foxpro tables with ODBC or OLE DB:

[Dbase ODBC](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/867190?wa=wsignin1.0)

[Foxpro OleDB](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/207595?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: i don't have a linked server ( or at least i think so ), i'll follow your tutorial and the foxpro oledb tutorial then i'll come back with some code and stuff to see how it goes. i've edited the post with some code i did while i was waiting for an answer